# How to convert set into dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary, set

What's the simplest way to convert a set into a dict? Say from `{'a', 'b'}` into `{'a': 0, 'b': 1}`? Ordering doesn't matter but it should start from 0 up to the size of the set itself.

Answer (score 7):

Just use dictionary comprehension with `enumerate`

```py
>>> s = {'a', 'b'}
>>> {k:idx for idx,k in enumerate(s)}
{'a': 0, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: dict comprehension is the way to go. Can't see any more pythonic than this.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `dict` constructor with `zip` and `range`:

```
>>> s = {'a', 'b'}
>>> dict(zip(s, range(len(s))))
{'b': 0, 'a': 1}
```

And a similar approach, using `itertools.count`:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> dict(zip(s, count()))
{'b': 0, 'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
set1={'a', 'b'}
dict1={j:i for i,j in enumerate(set1)}
print(dict1)
```

Output:

```
{'b': 0, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: Why call `sorted()`, when ordering did not matter?

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> a = {'a', 'b'}
>>> dic = {i:val for val, i in enumerate(a)}
>>> dic
{'b': 0, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: This assigns `0` to all the keys.

Comment: Your output is wrong. All keys are initialized with 0 values.

Comment: This solution was given by @ThePyGuy and me